# Running an if statement if counter > 5

Tags: jquery

I have a script that produces a table of data dynamically depending on the number of records returns by a query.

What I am trying to do is run part two of my jquery script if the rows in the table are greater than 5.

My script:

```
        Counter = 0;
        $(document).ready(function() {

            function get_data() {
                    $.getJSON("get_data_logos.php", function(json){
                    json = json[0].data;
                    var tr ;
                    $('table').html("");

                    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                        tr = $('<tr/>');
                        tr.css("border-bottom","2px solid #FFF");
                tr.append("<td width='15%'><div class='clientimage'><img src='../../../../conf_images/boards/" + json[i].ClientImageName + "'></></div></td>");
                tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='clientname-text'>" + json[i].ClientName + "</div></td>");
                tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='roomname-text'>" + json[i].RoomName + "</div></td>");
                tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='time-text'>" + json[i].RoomFromTime + " - " + json[i].RoomToTime + "</div></td>");
                Counter++;
                console.log(Counter)
                $('table').append(tr);
                    }
                });
        }
        get_data();
        setInterval(get_data,60000)
        });

        //PART TWO

        if(Counter > 5) {
            var my_time;
            $(document).ready(function() {
            pageScroll();
            });

            function pageScroll() {
            var objDiv = document.getElementById("contain");
            objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollTop + 1;
            console.log(objDiv);

            if (objDiv.scrollTop == (objDiv.scrollHeight - 550)) {
            objDiv.scrollTop = 0;
            }
            my_time = setTimeout('pageScroll()', 50);
            }
        }
```

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: We most likely won't know how to help unless you tell us what the problem is!

Comment: @James Douglas Hi, my question is, at the moment the pageScroll does not fire when the rows of data are greater than 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the if statement only fires once - when the page loads. I would syggest putting the it into a function, and calling that function every time the for loop goes around.

```js
Counter = 0;
for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
  Counter++;
  console.log('This is test number ' + Counter);
  test();
}
function test() {
  if (Counter > 5) {
    console.log('Counter is higher than 5!');
  }
}
```

That activates the function every time the `Counter` is higher than 5. If you want it to activate only the first time it exceeds 5, then just check if the value is six.

```js
Counter = 0;
for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
  Counter++;
  console.log('This is test number ' + Counter);
  test();
}
function test() {
  if (Counter == 6) {
    console.log('Counter has reached the value 6!');
  }
}
```